# Creating multiple interactive polygon buttons in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

My goal is to create a lot of polygon button. For example, if I input a number of 6, I want to have 6 polygons.

For example:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
SIZE_X = SIZE_Y = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SIZE_X, SIZE_Y), pygame.RESIZABLE )
red = (255, 0 , 0)

NB_POLYGONS = 6
for i in range(NB_POLYGONS):
      polygons = [ ( x1 + i * 50,y1) , ( x2 + i * 50,y2), ( x3 + i * 50,y3)]#With xn and yn some random cords
      pygame.draw.polygon(screen,red, polygons)
```

This example works and creates 6 polygons. But how can I make them responsive? For example by clicking on one of them to switch it to blue. In the code I provided I've put 3 points in the polygon, but I want to know if it's possible to do this with an arbitrary polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.draw.polygon()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.polygon) returns a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) bounding the changed pixels. Test if the mouse is in the rectangle and draw the polygon again with a different color:

```py
for i in range(NB_POLYGONS):
    points = [(x1 + i*50, y1), (x2 + i*50, y2), (x3 + i*50, y3)]
    bounding_rect = pygame.draw.polygon(screen, 'red', points)
    if bounding_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, 'blue', points)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you restrict it to only convex polygons, you can get pixel perfect precision by checking whether the mouse-click intersects it. This can be done by creating triangles between each consecutive vertex in the polygon and checking whether any of them intersects the point.

Checking for intersection between a point and a triangle can be done with [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).

Here's a minimal example:

```
def collide(point, polygon):
    assert len(polygon) >= 3, "A polygon must have at least 3 vertices."

    px, py = point
    n = len(polygon)

    for i in range(n):
        x0, y0 = polygon[i]
        x1, y1 = polygon[(i+1) % n]
        x2, y2 = polygon[(i+2) % n]

        area1 = abs((x0-px)*(y1-py) - (x1-px)*(y0-py));
        area2 = abs((x1-px)*(y2-py) - (x2-px)*(y1-py));
        area3 = abs((x2-px)*(y0-py) - (x0-px)*(y2-py));

        area = abs((x1-x0)*(y2-y0) - (x2-x0)*(y1-y0));
        if area1 + area2 + area3 == area:
            return True

    return False


print(collide(point=(10, 10), polygon=[(5, 5), (5, 10), (10, 10), (10, 5)]))  # True
print(collide(point=(20, 10), polygon=[(5, 5), (5, 10), (10, 10), (10, 5)]))  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't searched anything about this, so I think you can try this code:

```
import pygame, PIL.Image
pygame.init()

def polygonCollidePoint(polygonPoints, point):
    w, h = 0, 0
    for i, a in enumerate(polygonPoints):
        w, h = max(w, a[0]), (h, a[1])

    root = pygame.Surface((w, h))

    root.fill((255, 255, 255))

    pygame.draw.rect(root, (255, 0, 0), polygonPoints)

    root = PIL.Image.frombytes("RGB", (w, h), pygame.image.tostring(root, "RGB"))

    return root.getpixel(point) == (255, 0, 0)
```

It can be slowly, but I haven't been searched other ways to do this.

Edited: I have been searched something faster:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

def polygonCollidePoint(polygonPoints, point):
    w, h = 0, 0
    for i, a in enumerate(polygonPoints):
        w, h = max(w, a[0]), (h, a[1])

    root = pygame.Surface((w, h))

    root.fill((255, 255, 255))

    pygame.draw.rect(root, (255, 0, 0), polygonPoints)

    return root.get_at(point) == (255, 0, 0, 255)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).